# javascript function BiggerOf(array,value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function called BiggerOf(array,value) i need a javascript code.the function calculate how many array element Bigger than that value and print these element?
-Array=[2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19].
-value=8

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: so loop through the array and see if value is bigger than the index.

Comment: hint: `.filter(...).length` or just a loop with accumulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var noArray = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19];
function BiggerOf(arrayVal, val){

  for (i = 0; i < arrayVal.length; i++) { 
      if(arrayVal[i] > val ){
        alert(arrayVal[i]);
      } 

  }
}
BiggerOf(noArray, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function BiggerOf( array, value ){
    var result = 0;                 // a variable to store the result, it starts at 0
    for ( var i in array ){         // iterates the array
        if ( array[i] > value ) {   // checks if the current array item is bigger then value
              result++;             // if so, result is incremented
        }
    }
    return result;                  // returns the result
}
```

*Note: for future questions, please provide the code of what you tried, what problem did you encounter and state your problem as clearly as you can. We are not here to do your homework or guess your problem.*